# Is jQuery .append breaking my Rails form and causing it not to fully render?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

Running into a strange issue. I using jQuery's `.append()` to place a `<div>` containing a Rails form next to the paragraph tag a user selects in my Rails app.

First off, before adding the jQuery effect, I tested this by placing a the form on the page. It loaded, worked, and posted the user's text to my database correctly.

Second, I added this effect, and the `<div>` with the form does load, but weirdly, **you cannot click into it.** The text cursor will appear for a moment, disappear, and the user can not actually enter anything in the text_field.

Here's what I am running:

**view.html.erb**

```
    <% @posts.each do |post| %>
            <h2 id="title"><%= post.title %></h2>
            <div id="paragraph"><%= markdown(post.content) %></div>    
    <% end %>

    <div class="exampleToggle"> <!-- div that should append --> 
        <%= form_for :comments do |f| %>
            <div class="form-group">
            <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :username %><br>
            <%= f.text_field :username, class: "form-control" %>
                </div>
                </div>

            <div class="form-group">
            <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :post %><br>
            <%= f.text_area :post, class: "form-control" %>
          </div>
          </div>

    <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-success-outline" %>
    </div>
<% end %>
</div>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var whatever = document.getElementsByClassName("exampleToggle");
        $("p").click(function(){
             $(this).append(whatever);
            });
        });
</script>
```

As I mentioned, the form does load and looks how it should after clicking on a paragraph element; however, the form will not accept text input.

Also, for clarity's sake, here is the CSS involved with the placing the `<div>` to the right of the clicked paragraph:

```
 {
  position: relative;
}

.exampleToggle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  margin-left: 8%;
  left: 100%;
  width: 35%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

Any idea why this is breaking the form/form helper?

**EDIT 1:** For clarity, the central issue here seems to be the Focus effect. To try and fix this, I updated the Javascript to allow for value entry when the `.field` class is activated, but it did not fix it. Here's what I tried.

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var whatever = document.getElementsByClassName("exampleToggle");
        $("p").click(function(){
             $(this).append(whatever);
            });
        $('.field').click(function () {
            var val = $(this).val();
            if (val == "") {
            this.select();
        }
    });
        });

</script>
```

Comment: You have given `$("p")`, but where is the paragraph?

Comment: Good question. The line `<%= markdown(post.content) %>` uses a markdown helper, and each block of text from the table becomes a paragraph (but does not have an individual ID.

Answer (score 0):

You have given `$("p")`, but there is no p tag in your question.

Also you are looping the same `id` to different fields which is not correct, **ID should be unique**. Instead take the class instead of id.

You should take a class to the paragraphed_id field and should write the jquery functions based on the required classes.

Try this,

```
  <% @posts.each do |post| %>
            <h2 id="title"><%= post.title %></h2>
            <div class="paragraph"><%= markdown(post.content) %></div>    
    <% end %>

    <div class="exampleToggle"> <!-- div that should append --> 
        <%= form_for :comments do |f| %>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="field">
                    <%= f.label :username %><br>
                    <%= f.text_field :username, class: "form-control" %>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="field">
                    <%= f.label :post %><br>
                    <%= f.text_area :post, class: "form-control" %>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="actions">
                <%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-success-outline" %>
            </div>
        <% end %>
    </div>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var whatever = document.getElementsByClassName("exampleToggle");
        $(".paragraph").click(function(){
             $(this).append(whatever);
            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Made this comment above, but the markdown helper in the loop is used to create `<p>` tags for each block of text. So there are multiple p tags in each post -- this part is actually working. The form appears next to the correct p tag. However, the problem is that the form won't let me "focus" to input text. It's like the form itself is breaking. Hope that helps.

Comment: any error coming while focusing on the text fields?

Comment: Just checked. Nothing in the web console, nothing in the local server logs. Seems like something is blocking the auto-focus. I tried setting the z-index just as a guess but no effect.